# Trying to merge dictionaries together to create new df but dictionaries values arent showing up in df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

[image of jupter notebook issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyH1d.png)

For my quarters instead of values for examples 1,0,0,0 showing up I get NaN.

How do I fix the code below so I return values in my dataframe

```
qrt_1 = {'q1':[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]}
qrt_2 = {'q2':[0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0]}
qrt_3 = {'q3':[0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0]}
qrt_4 = {'q4':[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]}
year =  {'year': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9]}
value = data_1['Sales']

data = [year, qrt_1, qrt_2, qrt_3, qrt_4]

dataframes = []
for x in data:
    dataframes.append(pd.DataFrame(x))

df = pd.concat(dataframes)
```

I am expecting a dataframe that returns the qrt_1, qrt_2 etc with their corresponding column names

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `axis=1` in `pd.concat`:

```py
df = pd.concat(dataframes, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    year  q1  q2  q3  q4
0      1   1   0   0   0
1      1   0   1   0   0
2      1   0   0   1   0
3      1   0   0   0   1
4      2   1   0   0   0
5      2   0   1   0   0
6      2   0   0   1   0
7      2   0   0   0   1
8      3   1   0   0   0
9      3   0   1   0   0
10     3   0   0   1   0
11     3   0   0   0   1
12     4   1   0   0   0
13     4   0   1   0   0
14     4   0   0   1   0
15     4   0   0   0   1
16     5   1   0   0   0
17     5   0   1   0   0
18     5   0   0   1   0
19     5   0   0   0   1
20     6   1   0   0   0
21     6   0   1   0   0
22     6   0   0   1   0
23     6   0   0   0   1
24     7   1   0   0   0
25     7   0   1   0   0
26     7   0   0   1   0
27     7   0   0   0   1
28     8   1   0   0   0
29     8   0   1   0   0
30     8   0   0   1   0
31     8   0   0   0   1
32     9   1   0   0   0
33     9   0   1   0   0
34     9   0   0   1   0
35     9   0   0   0   1
```